# How to use cal(1) to print day of the week?

Tags: linux, unix

At the moment, I found that if I write `cal month year`, I get the calender of that month. Is there anyway to return the day instead of getting complete calendar? Beside this for 1752 the calendar is false and doesn't have half of the month? Any idea appreciated.

Comment: Consider adding some punctuation marks. Otherwise, we might die if we read it aloud.

Answer (score 0):

```
 date --date="MM/DD/YYYY" +%A
```

It will print you the day of the week

Comment: $ date --date="7/14/1789" +%A 
date: illegal option -- date=7/14/1789
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]

Comment: @JoshJolly Do you have any idea how to use before that?

Comment: 7/14/1789 is a tuesday... working in my ubuntu ... check if its right

Answer (score 0):

As it says in cal(1):

> The Gregorian Reformation is assumed to have occurred in 1752 on the 3rd of
>   September. By this time, most countries had recognized the reformation
>   (although a few did not recognize it until the early 1900's). Ten days
>   following that date were eliminated by the reformation, so the calendar for
>   that month is a bit unusual.

The short month displayed by `cal 9 1752` is correct (for the country where unix comes from at least).